# Usage of MatSlideToggleChange Event of mat-slide-toggle

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material

I'm trying to use a switch in a form to toggle the appearance of one of two dropdown menus in the same form.

Can I use the `MatSlideToggleChange` event emitted by a `MatSlide` class toggle to achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

you can use output change property to toogle its change value

```
<mat-slide-toggle
   [ngModel]="checked"
   (change)="changed()"
   class="example-margin"
   [color]="color"
>
   Slide me! {{checked}}
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

**component**

```
color = 'accent';
checked = false;

  changed(){
    console.log(this.checked)
  }
```

demo [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-czuhgz?file=app%2Fslide-toggle-configurable-example.html)

Comment: If you are using it inside a form element you must set the name attribute otherwise it will throw error. For angular 5+

Answer (score 13):

MatSlideToggleChange has two fields:

```
source: MatSlideToggle
checked: boolean
```

In .html file

```
<mat-slide-toggle
   (change)="onChange($event)">
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

In .ts file

```
onChange($event: MatSlideToggleChange) {
    console.log($event);
}
```

You would get output like this in the console:

`MatSlideToggleChange {source: MatSlideToggle, checked: false}`

If you were thinking about using the `(click)` event instead of the `(change)` event, I would recommend to use the `(change)` event instead for better mobile support when the user drags the `mat-slide-toggle`. You basically just inspect the value of the $event which is a `MatSlideToggleChange`.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="swFechaFinalPago" name="swFechaFinalPago">
                Fecha Final Pago? {{swFechaFinalPago}}</mat-slide-toggle>
```

**TS**

```
public swFechaFinalPago: boolean =  false;
```